# What happens if I call return; from Runnable?

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

I have Java Runnable where I am implementing `run()` method. There is some connection to server made in that run method and when it does fail, I am not interested in thread execution anymore and I want to quit it. I do something like this:

```
class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // connect to server here
        if (it failed) {
            return;
        }

        // do something else
    }
}
```

Now I submit this runnable into `Executors.cachedThreadPool()` with my own thread factory which does basically nothing new.

Am I safe to return from that runnable like that?

I looked into jvisualvm and I see that there is that one thread in thread pool + there are threads which are executing in that connection to the server logic and when I return, I see these connection threads are stopped, they do stay in the list but they are white ...

Comment: Yes, it is just a method call. Returning is fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not submitting a thread to the executor, you're submitting Runnables to it. Calling return in the Runnable does not cause the thread executing it to terminate. The executor is written so that it can run multiple tasks in the form of Runnables, when a Runnable finishes executing (regardless of whether it returns early or whatever) the thread continues, and gets more work from its queued-up submitted tasks.

Here's the code in the ThreadPoolExecutor#runWorker method. The line showing `task.run()` is where the worker thread executes the task, when your task returns then the worker's execution proceeds from there.

```
final void runWorker(Worker w) {
    Thread wt = Thread.currentThread();
    Runnable task = w.firstTask;
    w.firstTask = null;
    w.unlock(); // allow interrupts
    boolean completedAbruptly = true;
    try {
        while (task != null || (task = getTask()) != null) {
            w.lock();
            // If pool is stopping, ensure thread is interrupted;
            // if not, ensure thread is not interrupted.  This
            // requires a recheck in second case to deal with
            // shutdownNow race while clearing interrupt
            if ((runStateAtLeast(ctl.get(), STOP) ||
                 (Thread.interrupted() &&
                  runStateAtLeast(ctl.get(), STOP))) &&
                !wt.isInterrupted())
                wt.interrupt();
            try {
                beforeExecute(wt, task);
                Throwable thrown = null;
                try {
                    task.run();
                } catch (RuntimeException x) {
                    thrown = x; throw x;
                } catch (Error x) {
                    thrown = x; throw x;
                } catch (Throwable x) {
                    thrown = x; throw new Error(x);
                } finally {
                    afterExecute(task, thrown);
                }
            } finally {
                task = null;
                w.completedTasks++;
                w.unlock();
            }
        }
        completedAbruptly = false;
    } finally {
        processWorkerExit(w, completedAbruptly);
    }
}
```

Comment: yes you are right. I tested this, that runnable returns prematurely few times and there is still one thread active in jvisualvm during the whole life time of the JVM so that thread is reused when idle.

Answer (score 3):

It is perfectly fine to use `return` from a `void` method.  It just returns from that method which in this case will finish the thread execution.